# Getting "E: The repository '... Release' does not have a Release file." error message when installing package on Termux

Tags: termux

I've tried installing numerous different packages on Termux but keep getting roughly the same error: **E: Unable to locate package**

```
$ pkg install iwyu
Checking availability of current mirror: ok
Ign:1 dl.bintray.com/grimler/game-packages-24 games InRelease
Ign:2 dl.bintray.com/grimler/science-packages-24 science InRelease
Ign:3 main.termux-mirror.ml stable InRelease
Err:4 dl.bintray.com/grimler/game-packages-24 games Release
  404 Not Found
Err:5 dl.bintray.com/grimler/science-packages-24 science Release
  404 Not Found
Err:6 main.termux-mirror.ml stable Release
  Redirection from https to 'ww38.main.termux-mirror.ml/dists/stable/Release' is forbidden
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'dl.bintray.com/grimler/game-packages-24 games Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Metadata integrity can't be verified, repository is disabled now.
N: Possible cause: repository is under maintenance or down (wrong sources.list URL?).
E: The repository 'dl.bintray.com/grimler/science-packages-24 science Release' does not have a Release file. 
N: Metadata integrity can't be verified, repository is disabled now. N: Possible cause: repository is under maintenance or down (wrong sources.list URL?).
E: The repository 'main.termux-mirror.ml stable Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Metadata integrity can't be verified, repository is disabled now.
N: Possible cause: repository is under maintenance or down (wrong sources.list URL?).

$
```

Solutions?

Software details:

- Samsung Galaxy S20
- Android 13

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of Termux which can not be found in Google Play Store. Get it e.g. from F-Droid: https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.termux/

Answer (score 0):

Checking all the repository links, looks like all of them are already down:

- Bintray repo has officially shut down since May 2021
- `termux-mirror.ml` redirects to suspicious pages

The issue has been known and documented on the Termux' GitHub issue, [Issue #6726 - [README] Bintray repository hosting shut down | Error 403 Forbidden | Error 404](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/6726). The gist is to **change the repo sources, either by using `termux-change-repo` or by editing `sources.list` file.**

> #### What you should do as Termux user (only for Android 7+)
>
> ---
>
> You need to pick a one of the available mirrors by using utility `termux-change-repo` or manually edit `sources.list` by replacing the Bintray URL with value obtained from [Termux Mirrors List](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/wiki/Mirrors).
>
> **Beware of third-party scripts claiming theirselves as repository fixers! They could install untrusted GPG key and redirect your Termux installation onto malicious repository.** *Official tool for changing repositories is bundled within Termux and called `termux-change-repo`.*
>
> Usage of `termux-change-repo` is simple:
>
> 1. Select one or more repositories for which you want to change mirror by tapping "space" and navigating over list by up/down arrow keys. Tap enter to confirm the choice.
> 2. Pick a mirror, it is recommended to begin with mirror hosted by Grimler. Same as previously, navigate over list by arrow keys, pick mirror by space key and confirm choice by pressing "enter".
>
> Highly recommended to run `pkg upgrade` after changing mirror.
>
> #### If you get `E: Repository .. changed its .. value from .. to ..`
>
> Package manager can show you a notification with prompt which look like this one:
>
> ```
> E: Repository 'https://grimler.se/termux-root-packages-24 root InRelease' changed its 'Origin' value from 'Bintray' to 'termux-root-packages-24 root'
> E: Repository 'https://grimler.se/termux-root-packages-24 root InRelease' changed its 'Label' value from 'Bintray' to 'termux-root-packages-24 root'
> N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
> Do you want to accept these changes and continue updating from this repository? [y/N]
> ```
>
> It is completely normal. Answer "yes" to this prompt. It will be shown only once per repository, so package manager will ask you to confirm for `game-repo`, `science-repo`, etc separately but you will need to confirm them only one time.