# How to install netcat on Termux?

Tags: installation, termux

I want to use WireGuard on my phone to connect to WireGuard on my Desktop's WireGuard server. On another website, I have been advised to execute in Terminal (I use the Termux app) on my phone, the command `nc -4u -w1` I get "The program nc is not installed. Install it by executing pkg install netcat". When I try to install netcat, I get various repositories being a problem and netcat is not installed.

```
$ pkg install netcat
Testing the available mirrors:
[*] https://dl.bintray.com/termux/termux-packages-24: bad
[*] https://grimler.se/termux-packages-24: ok
[*] https://main.termux-mirror.ml: ok
[*] https://termux.mentality.rip/termux-packages-2
4: ok
Picking mirror: https://termux.mentality.rip/termux-packages-24
Get:1 https://termux.mentality.rip/termux-packages-24 stable InRelease [14.0 kB]
Ign:2 https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/game-packages-24 games InRelease
Ign:3 https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/science-packages-24 science InRelease
Err:4 https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/game-packages-24 games Release 404 Not Found
Err:5 https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/science-packages-24 science Release 404 Not Found
Get:6 https://termux.mentality.rip/termux-packages-24 stable/main aarch64 Packages [502 kB]
Reading package lists... Done
E:The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/ game-packages-24 games Release' does not have a Release file.
N:Metadata integrity can't be verified, repository is disabled now.
N:Possible cause: repository is under maintenance or down (wrong sources.list URL?).
E:The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/ science-packages-24 science Release' does not have a Release file.
N:Metadata integrity can't be verified, repository is disabled now.
N:Possible cause: repository is under maintenance or down (wrong sources.list URL?).

$ echo Test message | nc 4u -w1
The program nc is not installed. Install it by executing: pkg install netcat

$
```

<sup>[Original Termux output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2K3bg.jpg)</sup>

Comment: Related: [Getting "E: The repository '... Release' does not have a Release file." error message when installing package on Termux](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/250113/44325). Bintray has been shut down, thus you have to change the repo source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Termux installed via the Google Play Store, please remove it and replace with builds from GitHub or F-Droid. More info about here: https://github.com/termux/termux-app#installation

Run `termux-change-repo` to update your repos.

more info here: https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/wiki/Package-Management#package-management

for installing netcat, `pkg install netcat-openbsd` for using with command `nc` or `pkg install nmap-ncat` for nmap variant, command `ncat`